# Results of sorting an array are unexpected

Tags: ios, swift

I have a an array of objects that contains a date value. I have calculated the date differences and returned the number of days left. Now I am trying to sort it so it appends based on the object with least number of days left.

I have been able to use this function:

```
func sortList() {
    item.sort { (first: Item, second: Item) -> Bool in
        return first.days() < second.days()
    }
}
```

Which gives me this:

[image: this]

However as you can see the date which is equal to 0 is appended at the bottom.

This is how I am calculating the days difference:

```
func daysDiff(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar = Calendar.current

    let date1 = calendar.startOfDay(for: startDate)
    let date2 = calendar.startOfDay(for: endDate)

    let a = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: date1, to: date2)
    return a.value(for: .day)!
}
```

And this is how I am formatting it:

```
func days() -> String {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = "MM dd, yyyy"
    let date = formatter.date(from: itemDate!)

    let date1 = Date()
    let date2 = date
    let days = daysDiff(startDate: date1, endDate: date2!)
    if days > 1 {
        return "\(days) days left"
    } else if days == 1 {
        return "a day left"
    } else if days == 0 {
        return "Due today!"
    } else if days < 0 {
        return "Late"
    } else {
        return "\(days)"
    }
}
```

I am not really sure why this issue is happening.

Comment: this is nothing to do with the tableview - please update your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sort is based on the text from your days() function so you are sorting the data alphabetically based on your text. You should sort based on an actual integer value, not a string.

You should have two methods on your class.

1. `days()` which returns an `Int` instead of a `String`.
2. `daysLabel` which returns a `String` based on the result of `days`.

Use `days` when sorting by number. Use `daysLabel` when displaying an `Item` instance somewhere.

```
func days() -> Int {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    formatter.dateFormat = "MM dd, yyyy"
    let date = formatter.date(from: itemDate!)

    let date1 = Date()
    let date2 = date
    let days = daysDiff(startDate: date1, endDate: date2!)

     return days
}

func daysLabel() -> String {
    let days = days()

    if days > 1 {
        return "\(days) days left"
    } else if days == 1 {
        return "a day left"
    } else if days == 0 {
        return "Due today!"
    } else if days < 0 {
        return "Late"
    } else {
        return "\(days)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that does make much more sense. But could you please show me how you'd do the daysLabel function please?

Comment: It would be nearly identical to your current `days` method. But the first half would be replaced by a call to your newly updated `days` method.

Comment: Sorry, I'm way too new to this. Please help me with an example if you can, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: I actually did that before you showed me the example, but it was because I forgot to call the sort function! Thank you so much. I will take note of this for the future that's for sure!